# Looping a python "if" statement

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, python-3.x

I'm building a kind of question sequence as part of a program in Python 3.2.  Basically, I ask a question and await an answer between two possibilities.  If the given answer is not part of the two choices, I print a line and would like to re-ask the question until the correct input is given and then move on to the next question and repeat the same sequence.

Here is a snippet of code to maybe better explain myself:

```
colour = input("black or white?")
if colour in ["black", "white"]:
    print("Thank you")
else:
    print("Please choose one or the other")
```

So in other words, if the given answer is not black or white, I would like to print "Please choose one or the other", and re-ask the question, as long as black or white is not given.  Once black or white is given, I would want it to break out of the if statement so that I can ask another question in the same manner.

I've searched for how to do this but haven't found anything useful.  I'm guessing a while loop, but when I try it just spits out my last print string infinitely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while True:
  colour = input("black or white? ")
  if colour in ("black", "white"):
    print("Thank you")
    break
  else:
    print("Please choose one or the other")
```

Keeping most of your code, wrap it in an infinite loop and break out of it when the input is what you are looking for.

Note, the test for membership uses a `tuple` instead of a `list` since the choices won't change, ie are immutable and `in ("black", "white")` makes this explicit.

Comment: And it could even be shorted since the `else` isn't really necessary.

Comment: @jdi True. My goal was to work with the OP's original code and add the requested loop feature without introducing other changes. The code could be optimized/streamlined for sure

Comment: @Levon get rid of the semi-colon after break, it's unpythonic.

Comment: @jamylak ha ha .. sorry .. old habits die hard .. :)  many years of C and Java .... thanks.

Comment: @Levon I will remove my answer since this is the same, my preferred way of doing it.

Comment: @Levon Nah it's fine, better not to have duplicates :D

Comment: thanks Levon for your answer, I can more easily wrap my mind around the functionality of this method as a beginner =)

Comment: @TK492 happy to help, I figured I'll change as little as possible from your original code to help solve the problem in a clear/simple way.

Answer (score 5):

```
colour = None
while not colour in ["black", "white"]:
    colour = input("black or white?")

print("Thank you")
```

Or if you want to get fancy

```
colour = input("black or white?")
while not colour in ["black", "white"]:
    print("Please choose one or the other")
    colour = input("black or white?")

print("Thank you")
```

Comment: As a (very minor) matter of style, you might consider `while colour not in ...`

Comment: @lvc: I still have a habit of doing "if not foo" because of how it negates the result of the following statement: `not (a in b)`

Comment: Minor nitpicking on working answers. Solution #1 doesn't give the "error" message (ie "Please choose ...") Solution #2 has redundancy on `input`s/prompts.

Comment: @lvc I agree it should be `x not in y` although I don't think it is minor, this should be the only way.